# get url from new google site

Tags: google-sites, google-sites-2016

I created site by new google site. Now I need to get the calling url within the site by html. When using window.location.href  or document.URL it return something else then the url (e.g.  https://[1234]-sites-embeds.googleusercontent.com/s/embeds/code/inner-frame-minified.html?jsh=[] )

Is there anyway to get the original called url, e.g. https://sites.google.com/view/[name]/home?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although the New Google Sites have made a long way since it was launched in November 2016, it is still very limited in terms of embedding and frames. 
The only option is to use Classic Google Sites, as it allows you to use `window.location.href` through XML. XML are no longer available in the new Sites.